# Need Ping Request from TFS/Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, tfs, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I will make a "Store APP for Windows 8.1 " with Visual Studio 2013 and I need to check if the tfs-server is online/offline at https://tfs.xxx-xxx.de:8090/xxx/xxx/xxx (not my server but got the url and I have a acoount to create and test some tables with Sharepoint)

I use HTML/Javascript and the user should see if the server is reachable. What I need is to ping with Javscript or something else (ajax?). I'd also like some information on how long the ping was and some header information.
I created some Buttons for testing, I will delete them later.

***HTML***

```
  <body>
        <div class="main">
            <button id="button_server_ok"> Green</button>
            <button id="button_server_slow"> Yellow</button>
            <button id="button_server_offline"> Red</button>
            <button id="button_ping"> Ping  </button>
        </div>
        <div id="response">Response</div>
        <div class="status_bar">
            <h3>Server State</h3>
                <hr />
                <svg  width="50" height="50">
                    <circle id="server_ok" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                </svg>
                <svg  width="50" height="50">
                    <circle id="server_slow" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                </svg>
                <svg  width="50" height="50">
                    <circle id="server_offline" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
```

***JavaScript***

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args)
    {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch)
        {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Diese Anwendung wurde neu gestartet. Die Anwendung
                // hier initialisieren.
            } else {
                // TODO: Diese Anwendung war angehalten und wurde reaktiviert.
                // Anwendungszustand hier wiederherstellen.
            }



            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function completed()
            {

                var ok = document.getElementById("button_server_ok");
                ok.addEventListener("click", server_ok, false);

                var slow = document.getElementById("button_server_slow");
                slow.addEventListener("click", server_slow, false);

                var off = document.getElementById("button_server_offline");
                off.addEventListener("click", server_offline, false);

                var ping= document.getElementById("button_ping");
                ping.addEventListener("click", ping, false);

            }));
        }
    };



    app.oncheckpoint = function (args)
    {
        // TODO: Diese Anwendung wird gleich angehalten. Jeden Zustand,
        // der über Anhaltevorgänge hinweg beibehalten muss, hier speichern. Dazu kann das
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState-Objekt verwendet werden, das automatisch
        // über ein Anhalten hinweg gespeichert und wiederhergestellt wird. Wenn ein asynchroner
        // Vorgang vor dem Anhalten der Anwendung abgeschlossen werden muss,
        // args.setPromise() aufrufen.
    };


    function server_ok(eventinfo)
    {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "GREEN";
        document.getElementById("server_ok").setAttribute("fill", "#00FF00");

        document.getElementById("server_slow").setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF");
        document.getElementById("server_offline").setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF");
    }

    function server_slow(eventinfo)
    {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "YELLOW";
        document.getElementById("server_slow").setAttribute("fill", "#FFFF00");

        document.getElementById("server_ok").setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF");
        document.getElementById("server_offline").setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF");
    }

    function server_offline(eventinfo)
    {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "RED";
        document.getElementById("server_offline").setAttribute("fill", "#FF0000");

        document.getElementById("server_ok").setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF");
        document.getElementById("server_langsam").setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF")
    }

    function ping(eventinfo)
    {

    }

    app.start();

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this server does not have an cors header that allows you to try to do an ajax request you could try to load an invisible image from the server with an on error alternative url and check the url of the image. I would not know any way to get a round trip time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Cors is working I can login

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Feature detection for CORS
if ('withCredentials' in req) {
    req.open('GET', 'https://tfs.xxx.de/sites/xxx/xxx/xxx.aspx', true);
    // Just like regular ol' XHR
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Working";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Not Working";
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```